# My Ubuntu 18.04 is unable to detect Wired network

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I have sideloaded Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 on my Surface book. When I boot Windows, it does detect the Wired network just fine, but not the same case with Ubuntu.

Could someone please help me investigate how to solve this problem?

Details:

> ifconfig -a

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    ether 02:42:30:d8:dc:e7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 2527  bytes 185456 (185.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2527  bytes 185456 (185.4 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.104.141.216  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 10.104.143.255
    inet6 fe80::95a:7402:dd65:5960  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether bc:83:85:cb:b9:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 93574  bytes 122521784 (122.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 441  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 45205  bytes 4840762 (4.8 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

> sudo lshw -C network -numeric

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless [11AB:2B38]
   vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. [11AB]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 00
   serial: bc:83:85:cb:b9:1b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mwifiex_pcie ip=10.104.141.216 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:131 memory:b9500000-b95fffff memory:b9400000-b94fffff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: docker0
   serial: 02:42:30:d8:dc:e7
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

> lspci -nn | grep -i net

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless [11ab:2b38]
```

---

EDIT

One key thing I forgot to mention was it did work before I re-imaged the Ubuntu on my surface. I used the same image to Boot though.

Comment: What is your wired ethernet h/w device?  It may not be supported, either in your kernel's configuration, or at all.

Comment: I am not sure which is the device. I am on a corp network and just use a switch to connect the LAN Cable to my laptop. One key thing I forgot to mention was it did work before I re-imaged the Ubuntu on my surface. I used the same image to Boot though.